# change rectangleShape with a comboBox C++

Tags: combobox, c++-cli

Im working with C++ in VisualStudio 2010. I have a form with a comboBox that has a bunch of different items listed, Box1,Box2,Box3,Box4, ETC... I have a bunch of rectangleShapes that are named Box1,Box2,Box3,Box4, ETC... When I select one of the names in the comboBox I'm trying to make the complementing rectangleShape's fillcolor change from White to Black.

This is my Code under the comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged event

```
String^ x = comboBox1->SelectedItem->ToString();  *// x=name of the rectangleShape*
x->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
```

but C++ keeps looking at string variable x as a string. Im trying to make the above code work the same as this code,

```
Box1->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
```

How do I get C++ to see the string that is stored inside of x as the name of the rectangleShape?

Comment: `x` _is_ a string, you even specifically ask for it to be a string, and not a control. Doesn't `comboBox` have a `FillColor` atribute? I.e. you use `comboBox1->FillColor = System::Drawing::Color::Black;`.

Comment: It's actually not the comboBox that I'm trying to change the color of. It's the rectangleShapes that I have in the same form that I'm trying to change the color of.

Comment: Then you need to map the combobox index or string to the actual controls.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm very new to this. The string is suppose to only hold the name of the rectangleShape not the color.